# My computer is resolving the domain I own to a wrong one

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I updated the DNS from the Digitalocean DNS service and the DNS is updated. When my friends ping the address www.esports.mv its going to the correct server but when I ping from my computer its going to a wrong sevrer 202.71.99.194 < that server is wrong

Comment: DNS records are cached by your OS (clear with `ipconfig /flushdns`) and the name servers you and your ISP use (wait until the cached records expire or use a different nameserver instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, verify that you've not added your domain to your local `hosts` file. If it's not there then you'll need to just wait it out. Eventually DNS caches between you and your DNS server will expire and you'll be able to resolve the correct address.